Reduce runtime-Gurobi Optimization
from gurobipy import GRB
import time
from random import random,uniform

def generate_respondents_and_weights(n_respondents, total_universe):
    respondents = list(range(1, n_respondents + 1))
    weights = {i: uniform(1, 5) * (total_universe / (3*n_respondents)) for i in respondents}
    return respondents, weights

# Function to solve the model with multi-threading
def solve_model():
     # Number of respondents and total universe
    n_respondents = 10000
    total_universe = 20000

    # Generate respondents and weights
    respondents, weights = generate_respondents_and_weights(n_respondents, total_universe)
    #respondents = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
    prog = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J']
    orig = ['N1', 'N2']
    dayparts = ['Primetime', 'Daytime']
    genres = ['Drama', 'Comedy']
    originator_prog = {'N1': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], 'N2': ['F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J']}
    daypart_prog = {'Primetime': ['B', 'C', 'E', 'F', 'H', 'I'], 'Daytime': ['A', 'D', 'G', 'J']}
    genre_prog = {'Drama': ['A', 'C', 'D', 'H', 'I'], 'Comedy': ['B', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'J']}
    
    #weights = {1: 400, 2: 1600, 3: 1200, 4: 300, 5: 650, 6: 1000, 7: 1500, 8: 1450, 9: 750, 10: 1100}
    
    census_reach = {
        'A': 2000, 'B': 2500, 'C': 3000, 'D': 2500, 'E': 1000,
        'F': 1500, 'G': 2000, 'H': 1500, 'I': 3000, 'J': 1500,
        'N1': 7500, 'N2': 7000, 'Primetime': 9000, 'Daytime': 5000,
        'Drama': 7000, 'Comedy': 7000
    }
    
    tolerance = 0.05

    # Ranking scores
    ranking_ip = {(r, p): random() for r in respondents for p in prog}
    ranking_ir = {(r, o): random() for r in respondents for o in orig}
    ranking_id = {(r, d): random() for r in respondents for d in dayparts}
    ranking_ig = {(r, g): random() for r in respondents for g in genres}

    # Create model
    model = gp.Model("Calibration_Model")

    # Set the number of threads to use
    model.setParam(GRB.Param.Threads,4)
    model.setParam("Method", 2)
    model.setParam("Heuristics", 0.6)
    model.setParam("Prepass", 3)
    #model.setParam("Memlimit",32)
    model.setParam("Aggregate",2)

    # Decision variables
    x = model.addVars(respondents, prog, vtype=GRB.BINARY, name="x")
    y = model.addVars(respondents, orig, vtype=GRB.BINARY, name="y")
    z = model.addVars(respondents, dayparts, vtype=GRB.BINARY, name="z")
    s = model.addVars(respondents, genres, vtype=GRB.BINARY, name="s")

    # Objective function
    model.setObjective(
        gp.quicksum(weights[i] * x[i, p] * ranking_ip[i, p] for i in respondents for p in prog) +
        gp.quicksum(weights[i] * y[i, r] * ranking_ir[i, r] for i in respondents for r in orig) +
        gp.quicksum(weights[i] * z[i, d] * ranking_id[i, d] for i in respondents for d in dayparts) +
        gp.quicksum(weights[i] * s[i, g] * ranking_ig[i, g] for i in respondents for g in genres),
        GRB.MINIMIZE)

    # Constraints
    for program in prog:
        model.addConstr(gp.quicksum(weights[i] * x[i, program] for i in respondents) >= (1 - tolerance) * census_reach[program], f"Program_{program}_Reach_Lower")
        model.addConstr(gp.quicksum(weights[i] * x[i, program] for i in respondents) <= (1 + tolerance) * census_reach[program], f"Program_{program}_Reach_Upper")

    model.addConstr(gp.quicksum(weights[i] * y[i, 'N1'] for i in respondents) >= (1 - tolerance) * census_reach['N1'], "Originator_N1_Reach_Lower")
    model.addConstr(gp.quicksum(weights[i] * y[i, 'N1'] for i in respondents) <= (1 + tolerance) * census_reach['N1'], "Originator_N1_Reach_Upper")
    model.addConstr(gp.quicksum(weights[i] * y[i, 'N2'] for i in respondents) >= (1 - tolerance) * census_reach['N2'], "Originator_N2_Reach_Lower")
    model.addConstr(gp.quicksum(weights[i] * y[i, 'N2'] for i in respondents) <= (1 + tolerance) * census_reach['N2'], "Originator_N2_Reach_Upper")

    model.addConstr(gp.quicksum(weights[i] * z[i, 'Primetime'] for i in respondents) >= (1 - tolerance) * census_reach['Primetime'], "Daypart_Primetime_Reach_Lower")
    model.addConstr(gp.quicksum(weights[i] * z[i, 'Primetime'] for i in respondents) <= (1 + tolerance) * census_reach['Primetime'], "Daypart_Primetime_Reach_Upper")
    model.addConstr(gp.quicksum(weights[i] * z[i, 'Daytime'] for i in respondents) >= (1 - tolerance) * census_reach['Daytime'], "Daypart_Daytime_Reach_Lower")
    model.addConstr(gp.quicksum(weights[i] * z[i, 'Daytime'] for i in respondents) <= (1 + tolerance) * census_reach['Daytime'], "Daypart_Daytime_Reach_Upper")

    model.addConstr(gp.quicksum(weights[i] * s[i, 'Drama'] for i in respondents) >= (1 - tolerance) * census_reach['Drama'], "Genre_Drama_Reach_Lower")
    model.addConstr(gp.quicksum(weights[i] * s[i, 'Drama'] for i in respondents) <= (1 + tolerance) * census_reach['Drama'], "Genre_Drama_Reach_Upper")
    model.addConstr(gp.quicksum(weights[i] * s[i, 'Comedy'] for i in respondents) >= (1 - tolerance) * census_reach['Comedy'], "Genre_Comedy_Reach_Lower")
    model.addConstr(gp.quicksum(weights[i] * s[i, 'Comedy'] for i in respondents) <= (1 + tolerance) * census_reach['Comedy'], "Genre_Comedy_Reach_Upper")

    # Adding "Big M" Constraints
    M = len(respondents)
    for i in respondents:
        for o in orig:
            model.addConstr(gp.quicksum(x[i, program] for program in originator_prog[o]) >= y[i, o] / M, f"Originator_{o}_Program_Sum_Lower")
            model.addConstr(gp.quicksum(x[i, program] for program in originator_prog[o]) <= y[i, o] * M, f"Originator_{o}_Program_Sum_Upper")

        for d in dayparts:
            model.addConstr(gp.quicksum(x[i, program] for program in daypart_prog[d]) >= z[i, d] / M, f"Daypart_{d}_Program_Sum_Lower")
            model.addConstr(gp.quicksum(x[i, program] for program in daypart_prog[d]) <= z[i, d] * M, f"Daypart_{d}_Program_Sum_Upper")

        for g in genres:
            model.addConstr(gp.quicksum(x[i, program] for program in genre_prog[g]) >= s[i, g] / M, f"Genre_{g}_Program_Sum_Lower")
            model.addConstr(gp.quicksum(x[i, program] for program in genre_prog[g]) <= s[i, g] * M, f"Genre_{g}_Program_Sum_Upper")

    # Optimize
    print(f"Optimizing model...")
    start_time = time.time()
    model.optimize()
    end_time = time.time()
    elapsed_time = end_time - start_time

    print(f"Optimization completed in {elapsed_time:.2f} seconds (using {model.Params.Threads} threads).")
    
    if model.status == GRB.OPTIMAL:
        print(f"Model solved optimally with objective value: {model.objVal}")
    elif model.status == GRB.INFEASIBLE:
        print("Model is infeasible. Computing IIS (Irreducible Inconsistent Subsystem) to diagnose infeasibility...")
        model.computeIIS()
        iis_constraints=[c for c in model.getConstrs() if c.IISConstr]
        print("Infaesible Constraints:")
        for constr in iis_constraints:
            print(constr.ConstrName)
        #print("Infeasibility analysis written to 'model.ilp'.")
    elif model.status == GRB.UNBOUNDED:
        print("Model is unbounded.")
    else:
        print(f"Optimization was stopped with status {model.status}.")
        
# Print the results
for v in model.getVars():
    print(f'{v.varName}: {v.x}')

# Objective value
print(f'Objective value: {model.objVal}')

# Function to calculate percentage error
def calculate_error(actual, desired):
    return abs(actual - desired) / desired * 100

# Calculate actual reach for each category
actual_reach = {
    'A': sum(weights[i] * x[i, 'A'].x for i in respondents),
    'B': sum(weights[i] * x[i, 'B'].x for i in respondents),
    'N1': sum(weights[i] * y[i, 'N1'].x for i in respondents),
    'N2': sum(weights[i] * y[i, 'N2'].x for i in respondents),
    'Primetime': sum(weights[i] * z[i, 'Primetime'].x for i in respondents),
    'Daytime': sum(weights[i] * z[i, 'Daytime'].x for i in respondents),
    'Drama': sum(weights[i] * s[i, 'Drama'].x for i in respondents),
    'Comedy': sum(weights[i] * s[i, 'Comedy'].x for i in respondents),
}


print("Actual vs. Census Reach:")
for key in actual_reach:
    print(f"{key}: Actual = {actual_reach[key]:.2f}, Census = {census_reach[key]:.2f}")


# Calculate and print error metrics
errors = {}
for key in actual_reach:
    errors[key] = calculate_error(actual_reach[key], census_reach[key])
    print(f'Error in reach for {key}: {errors[key]:.2f}%')

# Check if all errors are within the 5% tolerance
all_within_tolerance = all(error <= 5 for error in errors.values())

if all_within_tolerance:
    print("All errors are within the 5% tolerance.")
else:
    print("Some errors exceed the 5% tolerance.")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    solve_model()


This is the gurobi optimization with sample simulation I tried but with 10k respondents and the setup defined above is taking hours to run the optimization with local laptop compute(4 cores) .
Is there any way to optimize this (because this test itself is a sample) and when I run it on 120k respondents,100 orig, 20 genre it is going to take much more time (full scale).When I forecast for this scale of data it was about 4000 hours.
Also if we were to use say aws cluster, what should be the required configuration to run such optimization at scale?I definitely want to balance cost and performance, ideally would like to run it in less than 3 hours for full scale.

No clue. But make sure you do not exceed the available RAM.
